# proper syntax for js/jquery comparative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have tried so many different combinations of this and they all seem to not work correctly and I know it has to be something with my syntax....

Basically, I have a row of checkboxes. Months Oct to Mar.  If only ONE checkbox is checked,  AND one of those checkboxes is either October or March, then trigger.

Here is my code. (I am already able to grab noofmonths correctly.)

```
if (noofmonths == "1" && ( $('#month_oct:checked') || $('#month_mar:checked') )) {
        tempbase = tempbase + 200;
    }
alert(tempbase);
```

The problem I am having is that it doesnt seems to care what months I have checked. No matter what month, I am always adding 200.... The noofmonths DOES work correctly though because if I have multiple checkboxes checked, this does not trigger.

What am I missing here?  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `$('someselector')` always returns a jQuery object even if no elements match `'someselector'`. And any object, even an empty one, is "truthy".

What you should do is either:

```
if (noofmonths == "1" && ( $('#month_oct:checked').length > 0
                        || $('#month_mar:checked').length > 0 )) {

// OR

if (noofmonths == "1" && ( $('#month_oct').is(':checked')
                        || $('#month_mar').is(':checked')) {
```

When no elements matched the resulting jQuery object's `length` will be `0`. The `.is()` method, on the other hand, returns a boolean.

Having said that, I'd consider a different way of getting that effect. I'd give the whole row of checkboxes a common class (unless they already share a `name` attribute?) and then give the special ones (Oct & Mar) an additional class:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="month" value="Jan">
...
<input type="checkbox" class="month oneonly" value="Mar">
...
```

Because then you can do this:

```
var $checked = $(".month:checked");
if ($checked.length === 1 && $checked.hasClass("oneonly")) {
    ...
```

That is, first retrieve all of the checked boxes into the `$checked` variable, then if the number was 1 and that one has the class that marks it as March or October... That way if in future July suddenly became "special" too you'd just have to add the "oneonly" class (or whatever you care to name it) to July in the html, you wouldn't need to change your JavaScript at all.

Comment: Thanks again! I a went ahead and added classes for cleaner code. :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome. (Note that the "month" class is necessary only if there isn't already an easy way to select all the inputs in one step, but obviously "oneonly" is needed either way to identify the "special" months.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `length` property:

```
var len = $('#month_oct:checked, #month_mar:checked').length;
if (noofmonths == "1" && len > 0) {
    tempbase = tempbase + 200;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KKyRK/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to test for the length of the matched query.

```
if (noofmonths == "1" && ( $('#month_oct:checked').length || $('#month_mar:checked').length )) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just selecting checked boxes, not checking if they are actually checked.

```
if (noofmonths == "1" && ( $('#month_oct')[0].checked || $('#month_mar')[0].checked )) {
    tempbase = tempbase + 200;
}
```

or `$('#month_oct').is(':checked');` will also return a boolean, or you can actually select the checked boxes, and check if the selector has length, as in the other answers.